# Is there a way to write an xml comment <summary> by single string

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, comments

Is there a way to write an xml comment  by single string

VS usually help to write such:

```
///<summary>
///
///</summary>
```

But i like to write less and want to write like:

```
///<summary .....   />
```

Don't you know how it can be done in way VS it can parse?

Comment: "i like to write less" - doesn't VS put that in automatically when you enter \\\? - Btw. `<summary />` is an empty node. Do you want to use it with an attribute, like `<summary content="..." />`?

Comment: sorry, meant `///` of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this will suffice for you:

```
/// <summary>Your summary here</summary>
```

Comment: Since the `summary` tag does not have attributes, and its text content is the actual documentation text, that's as concise as you can make it. *It would be nice if XML allowed `</>` to close an element, but that's another story.*